# Java getting unreported exception

Tags: java, hadoop, exception

```
    public void createDirectory(String path) {
        try {
            shellSupport.executeCommand("hadoop fs -mkdir "+path);
            logger.info("Directory "+path+" created successfully");
        } catch(Exception exc) {
            throw exc;
        }
    }
```

**Error**

> error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to
>   be thrown

If I remove try catch then code compiles and logger shows the message but directory is not created.

Comment: What `Exception` class have you actually imported?

Comment: java.lang.Exception

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it enough just to add:

```
public void createDirectory(String path) throws Exception {
    try {
        shellSupport.executeCommand("hadoop fs -mkdir "+path);
        logger.info("Directory "+path+" created successfully");
    } catch(Exception exc) {
        throw exc;
    }
}
```

That is: `public void createDirectory(String path) throws Exception` to your method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw a exception you have to declare it in your method signature. In your case that would be

```
public void createDirectory(String path) throws Exception
```

Or you could catch it without throwing

```
try {
    shellSupport.executeCommand("hadoop fs -mkdir "+path);
    logger.info("Directory "+path+" created successfully");
} catch(Exception exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
    // handle your exception
}
```